# Do /tellraw selectors refer to the reader or the executing entity/block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, server-administration

I have an arbitrary Command Block.

Using minecraftjson.com I set it up to `/tellraw` everyone: "*[ the selector @p ] is a new player on the server. Greet them!*".

```
/tellraw @a ["",{"selector":"@p","color":"green"},{"text":" is a new player on the server. Greet them!","color":"green"}]
```

When they read the text in the chat, what will they see? Will they read that **they** are a new player on the server (being them the player closest to themselves) or that the player closest to the Command Block is a new player on the server?

In other words, are selector locations and count in `/tellraw` commands relative to who reads or who executes?

Comment: Did you want to write `/tellraw @a`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the executor, that means that if Horst executes the command (with @a at the beginning), then it will always say "Horst". But I have to check when I'm home, that's in ~9 hours.

Comment: @Fabian yes, I did

Comment: Actually, I just found it in the German wiki. Writing an answer...

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but I always hate it when computer programs try to "encourage" social interaction by suggesting actions to take when something happens. If I want to greet someone, I will greet them, but I don't want to feel like I'm urged to be social just because I play a multiplayer game. A chat message like the one above can easily put me off the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selector of `/tellraw` is only the target for the message, it does not change the executor (like `/execute` does). So the selector is from the executor's point of view.

The last example [here](https://translate.google.com/translate?u=minecraft-de.gamepedia.com%2FBefehl%2Ftellraw) ([archive](https://translate.google.de/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=https%3A%2F%2Fminecraft-de.gamepedia.com%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DBefehl%2Ftellraw%26oldid%3D527445)) is pretty much exactly what you want and it says that all players will get the name of the player closest to the executor into chat.